# What does this sentence mean in terms of Java?

Tags: java, arrays, stack

> Your stack should be backed by an array of objects that should be resized in the event that it becomes full

I understand the resizing of the array and things but I'm not quite sure I get what it means when it says that my stack should be backed by an array?

I'm implementing an interface as shown below and I am also asked to do the above,

```
public interface IStack {
    public Object pop() throws StackEmptyException;
    public void push(Object o);
    public boolean isEmpty();
    public int size();
    public void clear();
}
```

Comment: Can you share the source of your statement ?

Comment: It means that the underlying component that hold the items in your stack should be an array.

Comment: A stack is an abstract data structure. It's saying that it should be implemented internally using an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create a class to represent a stack, i.e. a list that supports stack operations, push and pop, and this is what the users of your "stack" sees, but in reality you program it by using an array to store the elements. If/When the initial array is full, you copy the contents into a new and bigger array, the user of the stack being non the wiser.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your stack implementation should use an array to store the data. Here's an example for a stack of primitive integer type:

```
public class Stack {
    int[] data;
    int size;

    public boolean push(int element) {
        if (size == data.length) {
            resize();
        }
        data[size++] = element;
    }

    private void resize() {
        //logic to increment/decrease the size of the array
    }
}
```

Not stated in the homework, but I assume your stack should store any kind of object. You should do some modifications on the approach above to support such requirement (not done since it means solving your homework).

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing a stack you need some place to store your data. As you don't have a stack yet you need to take something else to "back" your stack. In this case an array.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is a part of your homework assignment and that they want you to implement stack that supports regular stack operations like push and pop. This stack should hold elements in private member that is array.

Since arrays cannot be resized in java you have to implement this functionality yourself, e.g. create new larger array and copy all elements from old array to the new one when smaller array is full.